# Problems with Instafeed and a new client id number

Tags: javascript, instafeedjs

I have been working with pulling instagram feed with instafeed.js I followed the process of registering a new application so I could template the pictures as I pulled the info.

I found this tutorial that styles the images efficiently so I decided to implements it:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
  clientId: '877c13677a614436ad3d65856a9f4c8c',
  limit: 20,
  sortBy: 'most-liked',
  after: function () {
    var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');
    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
      var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
      $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
    });
  },
  template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>'
});
feed.run();
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bmhdp

But when I change the client ID the images are no the ones of the client..

I am relatively new to the instagram API but I've noticed it s a bit laggy, I was not able to report this situation to them either..

Am I doing something wrong, please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself just by paying a little bit more attention.

The method that runs the function feed.run(); is supposed to be userFeed.run();

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the standard option "get". And depending on what you choose as get, you'll need to add the option for the that. So if you say:

```
get : 'tagged'
```

You'll have to add the tagName along with it. So something like

```
get : 'tagged',
tagName: 'anythingHastagYoulike'
```

That will pull photos by Hastag. If you want pull photos by a location, You'll do some thing like...

```
get : 'location',
locationId : 0000000;
```

Find the locations ID swap out the number. No quotes need for that.

So depending on what you are trying to pull from instagram, your 'get' will change and you'll need to add the appropriate endpoint for that. If you're just trying to pull an Instagram-wide image search by hashtag, you'll code might look something like this.

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
  clientId: '877c13677a614436ad3d65856a9f4c8c',
  limit: 20,
  get: 'tagged', // added
  tagName: 'anytag', // added
  sortBy: 'most-liked',
  after: function () {
  var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');
  $.each(images, function(index, image) {
  var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
  $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
  $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
  $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
  $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
  $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
  $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
});
},
      template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" />     <div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>'
});
feed.run();
```